# Text Mining from Images

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, text-mining, keras

I want to do the following project and I think the best way is using tensorflow/keras: I have photos as images from a list with prices of products and I need classify these text objects from the images such that i identify the product name and the price. 
So I think it is different from normal Image classification since my objects are text objects? 
First, I thought it is like object detection in images but I think i need more to take these texts to another neural network?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to a king of image auto captioning, and why not sentence alignement ! I suggest you to go over the paper *Deep Visual-Semantic Alignments for Generating Image Descriptions* which is one of the references today (by M. Karpathy).
The first step is about recognizing objects in an image and align sentences to them (done with R-CNN and BRNN) and the second is about generating new captions (CNN + RNN)

Even though it may be quite difficult to deeply go through, there is some code available on GitHub and it has been remade by a a lot of people with various implementations. [Here](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/deepimagesent/) is the summary.

Good luck !

Comment: Sorry but that’s too complex. I have not yet st this link because you don’t understand me or should explain why this is so complicated ?

Comment: I am a beginner and looked st the tutorial for handwritten digits classification from tensorflow. So, you could do same thing with words instead of numbers from the image? It is going about word classification from an image...

Comment: why should this help me? I have only names in this images and want to extract them..

Comment: It depends on how is your data. What do you have ? a list of predefined prices and objects ?

Comment: I have images with product names and prices within like from a receipt. So in a predefined pattern